# Function on Javascript. Not work

Tags: javascript, function

I have a file .js with one function. And starting another class I want to call this function. But do not know why, the function returns nothing. The code I have is as follows:

```
//Valida a data inserida pelo utilizador.
function validarData(){
    var dataValor = window.document.forms[0].data.value;
    if(dataValor == ''){ //Verifica se o campo data está preenchido
        alert('O campo data encontra-se vazio. Seleccione uma data!');
        return false;
    }else{
        var t = validar(dataValor);
        alert(t);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code in the file .js is:

```
function validar(data){
    return data;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Please Alert the dataValor inside the validarData() function

Comment: 1. where the `validarData` function is supposed to be called? 2. have you checked the console log?

Comment: Is the DOM ready when the function is called? What do you mean by _"starting another class"_? You do know that JS has no such thing as classes, right?

Comment: What I want is the following: I want to have a function in a file. Js, where this function takes a value and as appropriate returns true or false.
Then in another file I want to invoke that function and print its value.

How do I do that?

Comment: @DanielSousa We help you with a problem you have in existing code.. we don't give you something from scratch.  This isn't the type of site where you get others to do your work for free.

Answer (score 0):

Without the accompanying html to go off of, this answer is mostly shooting in the dark.. but, provided you attach the function to the submit event, returning the value of the function...

```
<form onsubmit="return validarData();">
<!--                   ^ - this in your submit event(just listing it this way for simple explanation instead of advanced event attaching) -->
```

And provided your functions are defined in the document head, or the body, your code [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/uS25d/):

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return validarData()">
    <input type="text" name="data" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```js
//Valida a data inserida pelo utilizador.
function validarData(){
    var dataValor = window.document.forms[0].data.value;
    console.log(dataValor);
    if(dataValor == ''){ //Verifica se o campo data está preenchido
        alert('O campo data encontra-se vazio. Seleccione uma data!');
        return false;
    }else{
        var t = validar(dataValor);
        alert(t);
        return false;
    }
}

function validar(data){
    return data;
}
```

Of course, that's also assuming you correctly link to your functions if they exist in other files..

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/script.js'></script>
```

Comment: What I want is the following: I want to have a function in a file. Js, where this function takes a value and as appropriate returns true or false.
Then in another file I want to invoke that function and print its value.

How do I do that?

Comment: @DanielSousa I'm sorry, but that isn't descriptive enough.. moreover, I'm pretty sure with the above, I did exactly that.